# Add argument to 'arguments' array-like object, performance test

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, v8

Hello I did some simple test: better way to add argument to arguments array-like object in javascript:

This shows that using Array.prototype.push.call is about 3 times slower (chrome), why?

http://jsfiddle.net/vhrs56nm/

```
function test() {
    Array.prototype.push.call(arguments, 123);
}

function test2() {
    arguments[arguments.length] = 123;
    arguments.length++;
}

console.time("test1");
for ( var i=0; i<1000000; i++ ) {
    test(1,2,3);
}
console.timeEnd("test1");

console.time("test2");
for ( var i=0; i<1000000; i++ ) {
    test2(1,2,3);
}
console.timeEnd("test2");
```

Comment: http://jsperf.com/argument-push  i use this to compare, so you can add more tests.

Comment: You did something different. In my example arguments array isn't array, but array-like object that represent argument list within function.

Comment: Wouldn't the fact that the jsperf benchmark declares arguments as a regular array instead of working with the `arguments` object skew the results? Here's a version with actual arguments object, the direct push obviously fails http://jsperf.com/argument-push/2

Comment: I guess it skew the results. V8 handles increasing elements in array-like object in different way than in regular arrays. I wonder why.

Comment: Yes. Now your jsperf.com example is same as mine in jsfiddle. Why Array.prototype.push.call is slower? Anyone knows?

Comment: In my Firefox browser the performance reported by the fiddle shows hardly any difference between the two methods, so it seems related to Chrome?

Comment: Yes. It is related to Chrome, and V8 engine. Node.js use V8 that is why I wonder what should I use in server-app with high load.

Comment: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#3-managing-arguments see *"What is safe arguments usage?"* - seems like you've hit the sweet spot (only use with .length and an [index]).

Comment: This is why I need add argument to arguments array-like obj:
`Array.prototype.push.call(arguments, some_value);
var readyToSend = JSON.stringify(arguments));` I don't want to create new array, because it isn't GC friendly.

Comment: @ElSajko but once you call `JSON.stringify( arguments );` your performance gains from the direct index access goes out of the window: http://jsfiddle.net/vhrs56nm/1/ (see the "V8 Optimization killers" article linked above).

Comment: @pawel: in this example you create new array object by [], this is what I don't want to do. Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/vhrs56nm/2/ Still Array.prototype.push.call isn't worth of using.

Comment: Side issue, but `Array.from(arguments)` gave me a 4x performance boost on FF vs. slightly slower performance than either of your tests on Chrome. And side side issue, passing in unknown number of args via the spread operator, then adding an arg to that array boosts performance ridiculously, to around 15ms in FF, (compare to the ~300ms for Array.from and the ~1000-1200ms for the other two). Probably not super helpful to you, but thanks for posting this question and prompting me to take a look at how current browser performance is re ES2015 features.

Comment: I have third solution, it seems to be fastest but ugly. What do you think? http://jsfiddle.net/vhrs56nm/3/ it needs to store some temporary array and reuse it every time, so new arrays will not be created and GC is safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Array.prototype.push.call` is about 3 times slower (chrome), why?

Because

- it's a function call (two actually), and those still cost something
- passing `arguments` around requires reification of the object [which kills optimisations](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#3-managing-arguments)
- [dead code elimiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination) is more complicated to perform

Comment: What do you think about this new third solution? Is GC safe then? And what do you personally think about storing some small temporary arrays in cases like this, I think it is ugly, but leads to nice performance. http://jsfiddle.net/vhrs56nm/3/

Comment: That looks reasonable to me. The temporary array will be necessary to avoid the odd semantics of the `arguments` object, yes. Imo, you should usually go for the most readable code, as performance rarely matters.